# Star rating bar works on chrome and firefox but not on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a rating bar code. Which works fine with chrome and Firfox but while I am trying to use it with Internet Explorer it's giving me problem.

1. Star images are moving away from radio button.
2. Mouse hover is also not working.
3. More over I feel it is not supporting CSS properly.

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.css">
   <script>
   function alert1(){
       alert("fine");
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <article>
   <div class="star-rating">

       <input class="rb0" id="rating-input-1-0" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" />                       
       <input class="rb1" id="rating-input-1-1" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="1" onclick="alert1()"/>
       <input class="rb2" id="rating-input-1-2" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="2" onclick="alert1()"/>
       <input class="rb3" id="rating-input-1-3" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="3" onclick="alert1()"/>    
       <input class="rb4" id="rating-input-1-4" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="4" onclick="alert1()"/>    
       <input class="rb5" id="rating-input-1-5" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="5" onclick="alert1()"/>    
       <input class="rb6" id="rating-input-1-6" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="6" onclick="alert1()"/>
       <input class="rb7" id="rating-input-1-7" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="7" onclick="alert1()"/>    
       <input class="rb8" id="rating-input-1-8" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="8" onclick="alert1()"/>
       <input class="rb9" id="rating-input-1-9" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="9" onclick="alert1()"/>
       <input class="rb10" id="rating-input-1-10" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="10" onclick="alert1()"/>

       <label for="rating-input-1-0" class="star rb0l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-1" class="star rb1l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-2" class="star rb2l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-3" class="star rb3l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-4" class="star rb4l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-5" class="star rb5l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-6" class="star rb6l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-7" class="star rb7l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-8" class="star rb8l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-9" class="star rb9l" onclick=""></label>
       <label for="rating-input-1-10" class="star rb10l last" onclick=""></label>

       <div class="rating"></div>
       <div class="rating-bg"></div> 
   </div> <!-- star-rating -->
   </article>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

b.css

```
    article {
        padding-left: 50px; /* arbitrary, to expose the "zero stars" area half a star to the left of the first star.*/
    }

    .star-rating {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    /* radio button stars */

    /* you can easily stuff the generation of these repetitive chunks of CSS into a server-side language like ASP */
    .rb0:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb0l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 0px; /* no stars */
    } 

    .rb1:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb1l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 16px; /* half a star */
    } 

    .rb2:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb2l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 32px; /* a star */
    } 

    .rb3:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb3l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 48px; /* 1.5 stars */
    }

    .rb4:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb4l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 64px; /* 2 stars */
    }
    .rb5:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb5l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 80px;
    }
    .rb6:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb6l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 96px;
    }
    .rb7:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb7l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 112px;
    }
    .rb8:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb8l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 128px;
    }
    .rb9:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb9l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 144px;
    }
    .rb10:checked ~ .rating,
    label.rb10l:hover ~ .rating
    {
        width: 160px; /* 5 stars */
    }

    .star-rating label.star {
        width: 16px; /* half star */
        left: -16px; /* half star */
        padding: 0;
        height: 40px; /* whole star + 2x padding (4px each for top and bottom) */ 
        position: relative;
        z-index: 3;
        float: left;
    }

    .star-rating label.star.last {
        width: 32px;
    }

    /* hide inputs (RBs and their labels) */
    .star-rating input[type=radio],
    .star-rating label.rb
    {
        display: none;
    }

    /* using icons found at http://www.easyicon.cn/language.en/icondetail/523835/ */
    .rating {
        background: url(http://cdn-img.easyicon.cn/png/5238/523834.gif) repeat-x top left;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 4px; /* 1x padding */
        height: 32px; /* whole star */
        width:0px;
    }

    .rating-bg {
        background: url(http://cdn-img.easyicon.cn/png/5238/523835.gif) repeat-x top left;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        top: -28px; /* 1 whole star - 1x padding */
        height: 32px; /* whole star */
        width: 160px;
    }

    /* IE8 fallback to radio buttons */
    .ie8 .star-rating input,
    .ie8 .star-rating label.rb
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .ie8 .rating,
    .ie8 .rating-bg,
    .ie8 .star-rating label.star {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Why you check if it work with Internet Explorer below 8 version ? now 2014 not 2011. Why use version 8 now ?

Comment: It should be compatible with all the versions and all the browsers. This is what best practice is all about

Comment: @alokverma since you're targeting "all versions", then text-only too?  They don't support CSS.  IE 7 is used by < 1% of the planet and isn't supported anymore.  Do you want it to support IE 4, too? (That's called the argument ad absurdum, fyi.)  I'm asking b/c it sounds like everything since before browsers is covered by your definition of "best practice".  Now progressive enhancement is another story... radios for the antiques and fancy critters for the current.

Comment: OK, sidenote.  "More over I feel it is not supporting CSS properly." and you're talking about Internet Explorer?  A bit of advice -- in that realm, be ready to get used to repeating that statement... every web developer must!

Comment: @JeremyMiller mate I am testing it and it is not supporting IE only can we do something with this code that it atleast it supports IE8 and above

Comment: "support" is the key term.  The answer is "yes, absolutely."  Start with the base system add CSS where supported and supplement where JS is supported.  Use feature detection instead of browser detection to keep you in a forward-moving developmental cycle. Oh, and for IE you will want to declare a DOCTYPE to have any degree of stable reference -- quirks mode is, well, quirky.